# String concatenation won't work using my class

Tags: vb.net, string-concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate two properties into one string like so:

```
public class thing 
    public property word() as string()
    public property count() as integer()
end class

Public class myApp
    dim a_thing as new thing
    redim a_thing.word(upperBnd)
    redim a_thing.count(upperBnd)

    'I go on to fill the a_thing.word and .count arrays
    'Then I try to display the results...but it doesnt work.
    for i=0 to a_thing.word.length-1
        debug.writeline("Word: " & a_thing.word(i) & "  Count: " & a_thing.count(i))
    next
end class
```

The for statement just displays:

```
Word: [the_word_in_the_array] Word: [the_word_in_the_next_index] ...etc,
```

with no new lines...

If I turn this into two debug.writeline statements, I get:

```
Word: [the_word_in_the_array] Count: [the_count_in_the_array]
```

This is what I want, but it doesn't help that its in the debug output...I need to put it into a single string. I've tried using a_thing.count(i).tostring, but it doesnt work.  If I look at the arrays individually, they have exactly the contents I want. But I can't concatenate them.  Whats going on here? Does it have something to do with suppressing the new line that debug.writeline usually creates?

Comment: How you looked at StringBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if there are Null characters at the end of the words in the Word array.  That would cause the behaviour that you're seeing

Comment: Yes, but I want them to both be on the same line.  When I put them both on the same line, though, everything after a_thing.word(i) doesn't appear ("Count: " & a_thing.count(i) dont show up).

Comment: Ah, so the contents of the Word array contains NewLine characters and you want to remove them because they're causing undesired behaviour?

Comment: I dont think the arrays contain newline characters.  If they did, I would still expect to see "Count: [a_thing.count(i)]" after "Word: [a_thing.count(i)", at least on the line below it, but I do not.  Also, if there were newlines I wouldn't be getting all of my debug output on the same line.

Comment: Check to see if your Words have Null characters at the end.  That can cause behavioru like you're seeing.

Comment: here: would this work:  if a_thing.word(i).chars(a_thing.word(i).length-1)=chr(0) then return a_thing.word(i) minus the last character?

Comment: It did work: the null characters were causing the trouble. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Cool!  Glad it worked.  I've updated the answer to reflect the problem you had.  Don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: Just click on the empty green tick below the voting buttons, to the left of the question.